# Configure single LTO tape drive over Fiber Channel HBA

Tags: tape, fibre-channel, pci-express, hba, lto

How do you set up a single tape storage drive over an FC HBA? As far as I can tell, these things are not "plug and play". The tape drive I bought is an lto-5 FC taken from a tape library.

I have everything on and plugged in, but I am not seeing the tape drive in the device manager, and with this Fiber Channel stuff I literally don't even know where to begin.

Links to any additional resources relevant to the topic greatly appreciated.

Windows 10

Tape drive : HP BRSLA-0901-DC

Fiber channel card : Broadcom LPe12000 FC Host Bus Adapter

Comment: Hi. You use that with a Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short: I found the most likely issue. There usually is some kind of super jumper attached to the PCB for server tray use. Strip it off and see to it not to loose it! All is fine now!